# Read the text file and process the file in Java

Tags: java

I have a file named "data.txt" and it look like this:

```
B,C,1,360,370,380,390,400,410,420
B,C,2,365,375,385,395,405,415,425
B,G,3,360,370,380,390,400,410,420
C,D,1,370,380,390,400,410,420,430
C,D,4,385,395,405,415,425,435,445
C,G,5,360,370,380,390,400,410,420
D,G,3,365,375,385,395,405,415,425
G,B,3,385,395,405,415,425,435,445
G,D,3,380,390,400,410,420,430,440
```

I have to do a function like this `Function(String s1, String s2, int x)` it will
output the value after the second comma from the left if it satisfies the condition: 
-s1 must equal the first value 
-s2 is equal to the value after the first comma 
-Finally return the first value bigger than "x" from the 3rd comma. Example Function ("B", "C", 364) = 1 and Function ("B", "C", 366) = 2. 
I tried to read the file line by line then split using this

```
    BufferedReader reader;
        String fileName = "data.txt";
        try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
            stream.forEach(line ->{
                System.out.println(line);
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So i can print the file in Console. 
I add split (). To take each character and compare it, but the results printed in the Console are not as I thought.

```
BufferedReader reader;
            String fileName = "data.txt";
            try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
                stream.forEach(line ->{
                String[] newline=line.split(",");
                System.out.println(newline);

                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Here is the console:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@8646db9
[Ljava.lang.String;@37374a5e
[Ljava.lang.String;@4671e53b
[Ljava.lang.String;@2db7a79b
[Ljava.lang.String;@6950e31
[Ljava.lang.String;@b7dd107
[Ljava.lang.String;@42eca56e
[Ljava.lang.String;@52f759d7
[Ljava.lang.String;@7cbd213e
```

I'm stuck at here now.

Comment: Okay, so the requirements are clear. What is your question? What have you tried? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: I will update the question now. Thx

Comment: You should look up `String#split` and `Integer.parseInt`; they'll help you here.

Comment: You are reading the file but you are not storing the result, what about creating a List that holds each array (`newLine`) or another list for each row and then use that list in the search method you are supposed to write.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I will try it now. Thank

Comment: System.out.println(newline) gives the reference of newline array and it is correct. If you want to print the content of the newline array you have to do something like this: for (String s:newline) System.out.println(s);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following does what you desire. It reads the file *data.txt* and locates the first line in the file that matches your criteria. If such a line is found, then the third field in that line is extracted, converted to an `int` and that `int` is returned by the method (named `function`). If no matching record is found, then method `function` returns -1 (minus one).

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class FltrStrm {
    private static int function(String s1, String s2, int x) throws IOException {
        Predicate<String> predicate = line -> {
            boolean accepted = false;
            if (line != null  &&  !line.isEmpty()) {
                String[] fields = line.split(",");
                if (fields.length == 10) {
                    try {
                        int number = Integer.parseInt(fields[3]);
                        accepted = s1.equals(fields[0])  &&
                                   s2.equals(fields[1])  &&
                                   number > x;
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException xNumFmt) {
                        // Ignore
                    }
                }
            }
            return accepted;
        };
        Path path = Paths.get("data.txt");  // replace 'data.txt' with your actual path
        Optional<String> record = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                                       .filter(predicate)
                                       .findFirst();
        int index = -1;
        if (record.isPresent()) {
            try {
                index = Integer.parseInt(record.get().split(",")[2]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException xNumFmt) {
                // Ignore.
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "B";
        String s2 = "C";
        int x = 364;
        try {
            int index = function(s1, s2, x);
            if (index >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + index);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Nothing found.");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code using the sample data from your question outputs the following.

```
Found: 2
```